# Why the dates 2014 Oct 31 and 2014 Nov 01 using date Object have same values in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, date

Why both dates in the below code have same `valueOf()` and `getTime()`?

```html
<script>
var endDt = new Date(2014,10,31);
var endDt2 = new Date(2014,11,1);
alert("getTime()\nendDt : "+endDt.getTime()+"\nendDt2: "+endDt2.getTime());
alert("valueOf()\nendDt : "+endDt.valueOf()+"\nendDt2: "+endDt2.valueOf());
</script>
```

We can see that both values is equals.

I want to get the values to lock the user if user try a interval greater than 31 days.
But when the user puts start `Date(2014,10,01)` and end `Date(2014,11,1)` the javascript interprets as end `Date(2014,10,31)`. When i do calc. with difference between start date and end date both values is the same.

```html
<script>
var startDt = new Date(2014,10,01);
var endDt  = new Date(2014,10,31);
var endDt2  = new Date(2014,11,1);
  
var diff  = endDt.getTime()-startDt.getTime();
var diff2 = endDt2.getTime()-startDt.getTime();

alert("getTime()\ndiff: "+diff+"\ndiff2: "+diff2);
  
diff  = endDt.valueOf()-startDt.valueOf();
diff2 = endDt2.valueOf()-startDt.valueOf();

alert("valueOf()\ndiff: "+diff+"\ndiff2: "+diff2);
</script>
```

Why are these values coming up the same, even though the provided dates are different?

Comment: The dates in javascript are a bit strange indeed. Check this out: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: Javascript Date months are 0 based so November should be 10.

Answer (score 8):

You are creating the wrong dates. Months are 0-based in JavaScript, so `new Date(2014,10,31);` is (theoretically) Nov 31st and `new Date(2014,11,1)` is Dec 1st.

Of course Nov 31st doesn't exist, so it's correct to Dec 1st.

From the big yellow box in the [**MDN documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date):

> **Note**: Where `Date` is called as a constructor with more than one argument, if values are greater than their logical range (e.g. `13` is provided as the month value or `70` for the minute value), the adjacent value will be adjusted. E.g. `new Date(2013, 13, 1)` is equivalent to `new Date(2014, 1, 1)`, both create a date for `2014-02-01` (note that the month is 0-based).